# Is it possible to log a firebase event inside Headless js?

Tags: react-native, react-native-firebase

I'm trying to log a firebase event when a user is receiving a remote push notification when the app is in the background/killed. My notification displays juste fine but I can't log analytics events.

I have tried initializing my firebase app with firebase.initializeApp(config), not knowing if it was initialized in a headless js task but it didn't seem to make a difference.
In-app events log just fine using the Debug View in the firebase console, as well as the notification_receive one automatically

```
export default async (message: RemoteMessage) => {
  const localNotification = new firebase.notifications.Notification()
  // setting notification props

  const displayNotification = await firebase.notifications().displayNotification(localNotification);

  firebase.analytics().logEvent('notification_test', { test: 'test123' }); // this doesn't work

  return Promise.resolve(displayNotification);
};
```

Is there a way to log an event here?
Also, any information on how Headless js works (besides official doc that I've already read of course) would be appreciated.

Thank you!